# メールアドレスを取得したい

Tags: google-apps-script

google formを使ってメールアドレスを取得したい。
しかし「設定」→「全般」→「メールアドレスを収集する」だと、
いちいちアドレスを入力しないといけないので避けたい。

そこで、回答時はgoogleへのログインを必須とし、
ログイン時の情報からメールアドレス（ログインID）を取得する方法を考えた。

しかし、自分のアドレスは取得できるものの（※）、
自分以外のユーザのアドレスは取得できない。
自分以外のユーザのアドレスを取得する方法を教えて欲しい

※以下のスクリプトでトリガー登録すれば自分のアドレスは取得可能。

```
function submitForm(e){
    Logger.log(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

「表示」→「マニフェストファイルを表示」で下記を記載していますか？

```
{
  ...
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  ...
}
```

`getEffectiveUser()` を利用するには認可が必要で、スコープを追加する必要があるようです。

[getEffectiveUser()のリファレンス](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser())
[scopeの追加の方法](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)